# How to use the Image with absolute path in a WPF project?

Tags: xml, wpf, image

In the XML I have some absolute reference to `Image` file. I need to show this Image in a WPF application dynamically without include the Images in the project forder or included in the assembly.

```
<imageUrl>C:\data\img.png</imageUrl>
```

I would like to know:

- is possible in WPF, how to do it?
- is the XML correct?
- should I modify escape something?

PS: WPF project is in a different folder from the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have code in place to read data from XML file. All you want is create `BitmapImage` and set it as Source of Image control.

**XAML**

```
<Image x:Name="img"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\data\img.png",
                                             UriKind.Absolute));
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.Freeze();
img.Source = image;
```

Of course instead of directly giving string, you have to read it from XML file and pass the string to Uri.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible and you can do it like this:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="MyImage"
           Source="{Binding Path=MyImageSource}"
           Width="200"
           Height="200" />
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // He must use the INotifyPropertyChanged method
    public string MyImageSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Here you get in advance path to Image from XML
        MyImageSource = "C:\\img.jpg";

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

If you try to bind an Image and error occurs that may well be a situation, you can try use the [`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

`TargetNullValue` returns your value when the value of the source is *null*.

`FallbackValue` returns your value when the binding is unable to return a value.

Example of using `TargetNullValue` and `FallbackValue`:

```
<!-- xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" -->

<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Test data -->
    <local:TestDataForImage x:Key="MyTestData" />

    <!-- Image for FallbackValue -->
    <sys:String x:Key="ErrorImage">pack://application:,,,/NotFound.png</sys:String>

    <!-- Image for NULL value -->
    <sys:String x:Key="NullImage">pack://application:,,,/NullImage.png</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyTestData}">
    <Image Name="ImageNull"
           Width="100" 
           Height="100"
           Source="{Binding Path=NullString, TargetNullValue={StaticResource NullImage}}" />

    <Image Name="ImageNotFound"
           Width="100" 
           Height="100" 
           Source="{Binding Path=NotFoundString, FallbackValue={StaticResource ErrorImage}}" />
</Grid>
```

It is desirable that these Images: ErrorImage and NullImage were included in the project.

See this links, for more information:

[`BindingBase.TargetNullValue Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[`BindingBase.FallbackValue Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)